# Am I able to compare pooled AUC values (from a meta-analysis) of two similar tests conducted in the same samples to establish which may be superior?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, meta-analysis, roc, auc

I'm new to all of this so I apologise in advance.
I'm currently conducting a meta-analysis and have pooled AUCs that represent the accuracy of two very similar prognostic factors in predicting mortality.
Both values come from the same group of studies that assessed both factors concurrently in the same sample. I can't reproduce the ROC plots, as only the individual studies' AUCs and corresponding 95%CI/SE are available, plus my pooled AUCs etc (i.e., I don't have access to the TPR/FPR for each threshold of each factor (2 factors are both ordinal variables)). Does anyone know if there is any way to compare the two overall AUC values for the 2 prognostic factors with the data I have available?